# Square brackets in #define statement

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, brackets, square-bracket

In my C++ code I want to be able to switch between using using arrays and variables, i.e. switch between `array[2]` and two variables `array_0, array_1`. However, there are a lot of occurrences of `array[2]` and I was looking for a way to quick switch between the two. I was trying to use a preprocessor `#define` statement.

```
#define array[2] array_0, array_1

int array[2]; //if define is included should become int array_0, array_1;
```

However, this gives the following warnings/errors.

> line(1): warning: missing whitespace after the macro name
>   line(2): error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token

From what I've seen, the problem is the square brackets. Is there anyway of making this work and have `array[2]` replaced with `array_0, array_1`?

Comment: what do you mean switch between arrays and variables? that makes no sense

Comment: No. But you can `#define` something that becomes either `array[2]` or `array_0, array_1`. But why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: I rather think that even if this worked, it wouldn't do what you wanted it to do

Comment: As a quick way to replace, try Shift+Ctrl+H?

Comment: What you _can_ do is use some constant like `ARRAY2` and switch between the array and the two vars by writing `#define ARRAY2 array[2]` and `#define ARRAY2 array_0, array_1`, respectively

Comment: If you really want to switch  like that, you will need a lot of defines to make that work, though. I guess you need to translate `array[n]` too?

Comment: Your macro is evil.  If I have the following `array[2] = 5;`, your macro will change it to `array_0, array1 = 5;`, which is ambiguous and will break the code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's not ambiguous. It's just the wrong semantics.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Looks like I'm going to have to do as Mr. Lister and T.C. said and have some constant that will be defined as either an array or a bunch of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. What follows `#define` must be an identifier, and `array[2]` is not one.

Comment: And as Mr Lister and T.C. said I could define a constant and switch between defining it as an array or a bunch of variables.